# Why is this code not running fully? It doesn't run line 53

Tags: python

I made myself an exercise with python since I am new. I wanted to make a rever LMC calculator ( Least common multiple ) but for some reason, something as simple as a print in a loop doesn't seem o work for me. I would appreciate some help since I am stuck on this weird issue for 20 minutes now. Here is the code:

```
import random
import sys


def print_list():
    count_4_print = 0
    while count_4_print < len(values):
        print(values[count_4_print])
        count_4_print += 1


def lcm(x, y):
    if x > y:
        greater = x
    else:
        greater = y
    while True:
        if (greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0):
            lcm1 = greater
            break
        greater += 1
    return lcm1


def guess(index, first_guess, second_guess):
    num = 1
    while lcm(first_guess, second_guess) != values[num - 1]:
        first_guess = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        second_guess = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        num += 1
    num = 1
    if lcm(first_guess, second_guess) == values[num - 1]:
        return first_guess, second_guess
        num += 1


lineN = int(input())
values = []
count_4_add = 0
count_4_guess = 0

for x in range(lineN):
    values.append(int(input()))
    count_4_add += 1

    if count_4_add >= lineN:
        break
print_list()
for x in range(lineN + 1):
    first, second = guess(count_4_guess, 1, 1)
    count_4_guess += 1
    print(first + second)
# this ^^^ doesn't work for some reason
```

Line 57 is in the while loop with count_4_guess. Right above this text, it says `print(first_guess + second_guess)`

Edit: The code is supposed to take in an int x and then prompt for x values. The outputs are the inputs without x and LMC(output1, output2) where the "LMC" is one of the values. This is done for each of the values, x times. What it actually does is just the first part. It takes the x and prompts for x outputs and then prints them but doesn't process the data (or it just doesn't print it)

Comment: A comment to identify which is line 57 would be very helpful.

Comment: oh right yeah that should help adding it now

Comment: Using globals to pass essential information into and out of functions is bad, it makes it difficult to reason about the code.

Comment: How else could I do it?

Comment: Pass parameters into the function and use `return` to update. Your `guess` function doesn't always return something.

Comment: If I pass those three variables then I won't be able to change their value which is what I do in the guess method. Also, I feel like I'm missing something here. Sys.maximize doesn't seem right "Your guess function doesn't always return something" doesn't it? the while loop gets to a point where the if statement is true so i think it always returns first_guess and second_guess right?

Comment: What is your code _supposed to do_, and what is it _actually_ doing? When I run it, nothing happens. Please describe those two things by editing your question.

Comment: @KamilSuhak `guess()` only returns `if lcm(first_guess, second_guess) == values[num - 1]`. If that statement is `False` it won't return anything (or more accurately, will return `None`, which is the default return value of functions)

Comment: You should be mutating global variables in your `guess` function either. Again, take in information as arguments, then return the values you will need in the caller

Comment: Almost all of your `while` loops should really be `for` loops, which would let you get rid of your various `count_4_X` variables

Comment: could you explain that a little more? I thought that in py, for loops were only used for finding stuff in arrays/strings? How would i transform ```while count_4_guess <= lineN: ..... print(something)```

Comment: for can iterate over anything...that is iterable. This might help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-iterable-iterator/

Comment: I edited the code to not use globals

Comment: @ChipJust like this? ```for x in range(lineN): whatever``` when lineN is 4 then this will execute 4 times?

Comment: You can do that, but you can also just iterate `values` directly. You know you have `lineN` elements in `values` already, because you added them in the loop before it, so you could just do `for v in values: do_stuff()`

Comment: You also have a pretty bad bottleneck in your `lcm` method. Since you're picking a random number from a _huge_ range, you have an _incredibly small_ window where the while loop will stop, most of which resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: So I've been looking at your code for a while, and frankly I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do. Are you trying to calculate the LMC for the given values? Your code and your described goal don't seem to match up.

Comment: I'll edit the code and add comments. What I'm trying to do is 1. Take an input, say x and then prompt for x inputs from the user. Each one of those inputs is an LMC that I'm trying to find the ingredients of. Say the user gives these inputs: 1, 12. 1 determines how many numbers will be after it and 12 is an LMC. LMC(x, y) = 12 I want to calculate x and y

Comment: @b_c also thank you very much for help. I would have never figured this out even up to this point.

Comment: I understand that "LMC" is the least common multiple (should be LCM, no?), but what does "rever LMC" mean?

Comment: Also, can you explain what "The outputs are the inputs without x and LMC(output1, output2) where the "LMC" is one of the values." means? Are you just grouping the inputs, i.e: LCM(input_1, input_2), LCM(input_3, input_4), etc? I think both your code and your question are in need of some _serious_ refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** From looking at your comments and edits it seems that you are lacking some basic knowledge and/or understanding of things. I *strongly* encourage you to study more programming, computer science and python *before* attempting to create entire programs like this.

---

It is tough to answer your question properly since many aspects are unclear, so I will update my answer to reflect any relevant changes in your post.

Now, onto my answer. First, I will go over some of your code and attempt to give feedback on what could improved. Then, I will present two ways to compute the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) (LCM) in python.

---

### Code review

---

**Code:**

```py
def print_list():
    count_4_print = 0
    while count_4_print < len(values):
        print(values[count_4_print])
        count_4_print += 1
```

**Notes:**

- Where are the parameters? It was already mentioned in a few comments, but the importance of this cannot be stressed enough! (see the note at the beginning of my comment)
- It appears that you are trying to print each element of a list on a new line. You can do that with `print(*my_list, sep='\n')`.
- That `while` loop is not how you should iterate over the elements of a list. Instead, use a `for` loop: `for element in (my_list):`.

---

**Code:**

```py
def lcm(x, y):
    if x > y:
        greater = x
    else:
        greater = y
    while True:
        if (greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0):
            lcm1 = greater
            break
        greater += 1
    return lcm1
```

**Notes:**

- This is not a correct algorithm for the LCM, since it crashes when both numbers are 0.
- The comparison of `a` and `b` can be replaced with `greater = max(x, y)`.
- See the solution I posted below for a different way of writing this same algorithm.

---

**Code:**

```py
def guess(index, first_guess, second_guess):
    num = 1
    while lcm(first_guess, second_guess) != values[num - 1]:
        first_guess = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        second_guess = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        num += 1
    num = 1
    if lcm(first_guess, second_guess) == values[num - 1]:
        return first_guess, second_guess
        num += 1
```

**Notes:**

- The line `num += 1` comes immediately after `return first_guess, second_guess`, which means it is never executed. Somehow the mistakes cancel each other out since, as far as I can tell, it wouldn't do anything anyway if it were executed.
- `if lcm(first_guess, second_guess) == values[num - 1]:` is completely redundant, since the `while` loop above checks the exact same condition.
- In fact, not only is it redundant it is also fundamentally broken, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613725/why-is-this-code-not-running-fully-it-doesnt-run-line-53#comment103538066_58613725) by user b_c.
- Unfortunately I cannot say much more on this function since it is too difficult for me to understand its purpose.

---

**Code:**

```py
lineN = int(input())
values = []
count_4_add = 0
count_4_guess = 0

for x in range(lineN):
    values.append(int(input()))
    count_4_add += 1

    if count_4_add >= lineN:
        break
print_list()
```

**Notes:**

- As explained previously, `print_list()` should not be a thing.
- `lineN` should be changed to `line_n`, or even better, something like `num_in_vals`.
- `count_4_add` will always be equal to `lineN` at the end of your `for` loop.
- Building on the previous point, the check `if count_4_add >= lineN` is useless.
- In conclusion, `count_4_add` and `count_4_guess` are completely unnecessary and detrimental to the program.
- The `for` loop produces values in the variable `x` which is never used. You can replace an unused variable with `_`: `for _ in range(10):`.
- Since your input code is simple you could probably get away with something like `in_vals = [int(input(f'Enter value number {i}: ')) for i in range(1, num_in_vals+1)]`. Again, this depends on what it is you're actually trying to do.

---

### LCM Implementations

---

According to the Wikipedia article referenced earlier, the best way to calculate the LCM is using the greatest common denominator.

```py
import math


def lcm(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    if a == b:
        res = a
    else:
        res = abs(a * b) // math.gcd(a, b)
    return res
```

---

This second method is one possible brute force solution, which is similar to how the one you are currently using should be written.

```py
def lcm(a, b):
    if a == b:
        res = a
    else:
        max_mult = a * b
        res = max_mult
        great = max(a, b)
        small = min(a, b)

        for i in range(great, max_mult, great):
            if i % small == 0:
                res = i
                break
    return res
```

---

This final method works for any number of inputs.

```py
import math
import functools


def lcm_simp(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    if a == b:
        res = a
    else:
        res = abs(a * b) // math.gcd(a, b)
    return res


def lcm(*args: int) -> int:
    return functools.reduce(lcm_simp, args)
```

---

Oof, that ended up being way longer than I expected. Anyway, let me know if anything is unclear, if I've made a mistake, or if you have any further questions! :)

Comment: I guess that your comment is right. I tried something that isn't possible in my skill level. I will thoroughly study your answer and rewrite the code entirely. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilSuhak for some additional reading in regards to some of the content in this answer, see [value unpacking (the `*` operator)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @KamilSuhak I hope I didn’t come off as too harsh! b_c has the right idea, I will try to add a few more relevant links myself. I should also be adding a slightly different LCM function.

Comment: Unfortunately SO won’t let me tag more than one person. @b_c

Comment: No worries :) it's a good answer IMO, just wanted to add some supporting info.

Comment: Btw @KamilSuhak you can accept this answer if you find it suitable.